# replace textarea in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to Replace a %%%VERSION%%% text, the text is coming from an tinyMCE editor.

looks like this.

```
$("#description textarea").val($("#description textarea").val().replace(/%%%VERSION%%%/g, STAT_VERSION_INFO));
```

The value of the textearea is:

```
<textarea rows="20" cols="117" name="description" id="description">Some code version info: %%%VERSION%%%</textarea>
```

But i can't make it replace anything.

Comment: what is the value of $('#description textarea') ?

Comment: I just updated the question :)

Comment: I reimplemented the code and your basic idea is sound. But as mentioned below $('#description textarea') does not match your textarea. Basically your selector is wrong so use one of the answers below and you should be golden!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `html()` for textareas...

```
var txt = $("#description");
txt.html(txt.html().replace(/%%%VERSION%%%/g, '');
```

Answer (score 1):

To select: $("#description textarea")  => $("textarea#description") or just $("#description")

To do the changes:

```
var textarea = $("textarea#description");
var text = textarea.html().replace(/%%%VERSION%%%/g, '');
textarea.html(text);
```

Comment: As i told @Darin Dimitrov this dosen't seems to have any effects on the VERSION tags.. ( I know about the above text ). thx

Answer (score 1):

Change .val() to .html() and it works: 
Example here
http://jsbin.com/uwidu/

Answer (score 0):

Just replace `$("#description textarea")` with `$("#description")` or `$("textarea#description")`. The first selector will look for a `textarea` inside a DOM element with `id=description`, while in your case it is the `textarea` that has `id=description`.

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: I tried your solution, but nothing seems to fix it :S 
If i replace another text instead of the %%%VERSION%%%, it works fine... but not with the version tags :S

Comment: Do you have more than one element id'd with #description?

Comment: No, nothing.. :-( 

Could it be the replace(/%%%VERSION%%%/g
That need to be changed ?

The current text looks like this: /static/%%%VERSION%%%/

Comment: Your regex is fine. I recreated it as you specified in the question and it works just fine in firefox 3.5.